# Can't open port 465 on Manjaro/Arch

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, manjaro, smtp, port

I have been trying to send an email to gmail through nodemailer, but it gave me the following error:

```
Error: queryA EREFUSED smtp.gmail.com
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:dns:209:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'EDNS',
  syscall: 'queryA',
  hostname: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  command: 'CONN'
```

After extensive digging, I found out that the problem is probably due to port 465 being closed (which is the port for smtps. Took me a while to figure out how to know if the port is closed. When checking whether port 465 is closed or not using `nmap` here is the output:

```
Host is up (0.0017s latency).

PORT    STATE  SERVICE
465/tcp closed smtps
```

and to make sure, this is the output for my open ports using `nmap` as well.

```
Host is up (0.013s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
53/tcp  open  domain
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

I tried opening the port using `iptables` :

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
```

but it still won't open, what am I missing?

Comment: Be aware that portscanning without permission consitutes a crime in some jursidictions.

Comment: A port that `nmap` reports as "closed" is in fact open in the firewall, but there is no listener. If the port were closed in your firewall, `nmap` would say that it's "filtered". See also https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html.